# DCPcrypt encryption decrypt in PyCrypto

Tags: python, delphi, encryption, pycrypto

I am working to decrypt data that was encrypted with DCPcrypt using Rijndael.  I wanted to use Python to decrypt it but I'm running into issues.  I'll mention that I'm not particularly crypto savvy (I took a college course, but that's about it) and I'm also not a Delphi programmer, so that is also probably hindering my efforts to decipher what precisely DCPcrypt is doing.

This is the meat of the Delphi code:

```
Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
begin
Cipher:= TDCP_rijndael.Create(nil);
Cipher.InitStr(PasswordField.Text);
Cipher.EncryptCBC(encryptString[1],encryptString[1],Length(encryptString));
```

So the implementation uses a key (obtained from the password field) but no IV.  PyCrypto on the other hand requires an IV.  Searching through the internals of the DCPcrypt code, it appears that if the IV is nil, then an ECB encryption is used to populate the IV from a string of 0xff?

```
procedure TDCP_rijndael.Init(var Key; Size: longint; IVector: pointer);
....
  if IVector= nil then
  begin
    FillChar(IV,Sizeof(IV),$FF);
    {$IFDEF CFORM}Encrypt(IV,IV){$ELSE}RijndaelEncryptECB(Data,IV,IV){$ENDIF};
    Move(IV,LB,Sizeof(LB));
  end
```

It appears that I'm using a static IV.  However, I am not able to make this work.  Here's my implementation in PyCrypto.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
key = "password"
s = hashlib.sha1()
s.update(key)
key = s.digest()
key = key[:16]

# Set up the IV, note that in ECB the third parameter to the AES.new function is ignored since ECB doesn't use an IV
ecb = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB, '\xff' * 16)
iv = ecb.encrypt('\xff' * 16)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
msg = cipher.decrypt(ct[:16])
```

I have some plain text that was encrypted using the Delphi code and then base64 encoded.  The key used was the string password, as hardcoded in above.  Using my implementation, I decrypt a bunch of garbled bytes.

k8b+uce5Fkp7Hbk/CaGYcuEWTfxlI05as88lJL0mHmJxLsKWqki2YwiFPU9Rx8qiUC2cvWZrQIOnkw==

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like `InitStr` is the relevant function...are you certain it uses the first 16 bytes of the SHA-1 hash as the key data?

Comment: Find out how *you* can specify the IV, so that you control it. They have to be the same at both sides. Also, see my remarks about padding at stackoverflow.com/questions/11717471/delphi-encrypt-compendiun-5-2-vs-chilkat-encryption/

Comment: @Jan, I suppose I should have been more specific with regards to the Delphi code.  That code is already written and in production.  I do not have the option to change it.  Otherwise, I would certainly specify my IV.

Comment: @nneonneo, InitStr is the relevant function but I think it calls Init under the hood.  I'm pretty sure it uses the first 16 bytes of the SHA1.  I'll post the relevant code tonight.

Comment: Do you at least have a copy of delphi so you can experiment with both sides of the equation?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Delphi, but I did download the free pascal compiler to use on Linux.  I have a copy of the Delphi program compiled from source to work with though.

Comment: I'm afraid it's gonna be digging into the DCPCrypt code then (you already started that) with some sample program that you build in Delphi, to follow what it does exactly, then trying to reproduce it Python. If you're 'not a Delphi programmer', 'extremely new to Python' and 'not particularly crypto savvy' you took on quite a job. It looks doable, but maybe should should pull in some auxiliary troops.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not extremely new to Python, but the other two are correct.  I expected the DCPcrypt implementation to be fairly standard with regards to IV generation.

Answer (score 0):

A random assortment of suggestions and thoughts:

1. Static IVs are generally a security risk as they open the door to known plaintext attacks.
2. Looking at the dcpcrypt source, it looks like there is a method to specify an IV. Any reason not to, if for no other reason than to eliminate incorrect IV as an error source?
3. Likewise, you could experiment with ECB instead of CBC to eliminate the IV altogether and isolate whether the problem is in the IV or elsewhere (key, data, or configuration).

Comment: I suppose I should have been more specific with regards to the Delphi code. That code is already written and in production. I do not have the option to change it. Otherwise, I would certainly specify my IV.  I'm stuck with the Delphi code as written and have to make the Python work around it.

Comment: I thought as much. Suggestion 3 stands - try switching to ecb mode temporarily to help identify whether you have an IV problem or a key (/data?) problem.

Comment: Ooh, also you could try writing test code to drive the DCPCrypt side and force the IV to what you think the IV should be and compare it to the output when you don't set the IV. Crypto and auth are a serious PITA because any mistake randomizes everything. Any little experiment you can do to figure out which side of the task has the problem is a Real Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I'm **extremely** new to Python, but try this:
Try changing

```
key = key[:16]
```

to

```
key = key + bytes([0,0,0,0])
```

This will give you a 24 byte key which, I think, should work.

DCP allows any length of key whereas Crypto insists on keys of 16, 24 or 32 bytes. By default DCP will use SHA1 to generate the key, which is then 20 bytes long. Based on this DCP uses logic for keylength <= 24 and just zero pads the key rather than logic for keylength <= 16 which is the effect that key[:16] is having.

Also, don't know if this is just a typo but try changing the AES mode

```
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
```

to

```
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

That will give a decryption of your input. But then you'll need to consider padding of the original source text because DCP does not pad (I think) but Crypto requires multiples of 16 for decryption.